# Arraylist and List in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Could someone explain the meaning of the following code, especially ArrayList and List and why do we need to use both?

```
String [] forecastArray =
            {
                    "Today - Sunny - 35/30",
                    "Tomorrow - Foggy - 33/28",
                    "Wednesday - Cloudy - 33/26",
                    "Thursday - Sleepy - 30/24",
                    "Friday - Bunking - 36/34",
                    "Saturday - Trapped - 38/35",
                    "Sunday - Heavy Rain - 32/28"
            };
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(forecastArray);

    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(myList);
```

Comment: Google polymorphism in Java

Comment: One  point is missing in the answers so far: `myList` is a `List` backed by the `forecastArray` and is immuteable. You won't be able to change it. `weekForecast` is backed by a copy of that array and can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is an interface. ArrayList is an implementation of that interface.

Basically here Arrays.asList(forecastArray) method returns a List but caller doesn't aware of which instance is returns. so first assign to list then try to initilize the Arraylist.

or You can do like as shown below.

List weekForecast = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

Answer (score 3):

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface. [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is an implementation of that interface. It's generally recommended to program to the interface. That way you could switch to a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and not change a return type or other code later on. This is an example of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: And the list returned by `Arrays.asList`` is neither an `ArrayList` nor a `LinkedList` - indeed, it's a type you don't have access to, so you *can't* use the actual type.

Comment: This info is great. My question is why do we need to pass it as Arrays.asList(forecastArray) instead of simply forecastArray.

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't have a constructor that takes an array.

Answer (score 1):

*Elliot Frish* has clearly explained the first part.

In your particular case,

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(forecastArray);

List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(myList);
```

are not the same.

Because the `List` instance returned by `Arrays.asList` is not same as `java.utils.ArrayList`. `ArrayList` returned is a `private static class` inside `Arrays` class.

Since both `ArrayList`s (in Arrays as well as in collections) *implement* `List` interface, you can assign them to a `List`. **Code to the interface** :)

Note : `ArrayList<String> myList = Arrays.asList(someArray);` --> doesn't compile